# all my objects in my scene are moving

Tags: modeling, animation, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to animate a vault door that I'm modeling but when I rotate the handle the whole scene moves not together but as individual pieces and none of the parts are parented or joined (except for my handles)

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: i dont know how to link my blend file

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/jPK5l7Rb

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck proportional editing here:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: glad i could help. If my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you and happy blending!